# Google Experiments Server Side Variation

Tags: server-side, google-experiments

I'm trying to implement Google server-side experiments by following this reference:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-server-side

My goal is to let Google decide which variation I should show to user from the experiment.
I have figured out that this can be achieved by setting "servingFramework" option to API.

I'm stuck on which steps I should complete to get the variation chosen by Google?

The main question is - how can I achieve the same results as from the following example, but server-side:

```
 var variation = cxApi.chooseVariation();
```

This is necessary because first of all, I need to get variation and just after that to show it to the user.

Comment: I have solved it like this:
<pre>

$googleAPI  =   ''; // googleAPI

$serviceExperiments =   $googleAPI->getService('Experiments')->setId("experiment_id");
 $serviceExperiments->setCacheTtl(500);
$serviceExperiments->setCacheDir(CACHE);
$experimentData     =   $serviceExperiments->getData();

# $mt_random = (mt_rand(0, 10) / 100 );
$mt_random = (float) number_format((float)rand()/(float)getrandmax(), 2, '.', '');

if( ($mt_random <= $experimentData["participation"]) !== true ) {
return;
}
<pre>

Answer (score 0):

According to [deividaspetraitis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3185908/deividaspetraitis) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919682/google-experiments-server-side-variation#comment42452035_23919682):

> I have solved it like this:

```
$googleAPI = ''; // googleAPI
$serviceExperiments = $googleAPI->getService('Experiments')>setId("experiment_id");
$serviceExperiments->setCacheTtl(500);
$serviceExperiments->setCacheDir(CACHE);
$experimentData = $serviceExperiments->getData();
# $mt_random = (mt_rand(0, 10) / 100 );
$mt_random = (float) number_format((float)rand()/(float)getrandmax(), 2, '.', '');
if( ($mt_random <= $experimentData["participation"]) !== true ) { return; }
```